# .htaccess not redirecting properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've gone through stackoverflow.com quiet a bit but I believe I didn't find what I was looking for. So, Here it goes. I have a .htaccess file which redirects properly but I have a remote test server, which it seems doesn't redirect as my developer machine does, could that might be the server's apache2 handler isn't configured properly?
Okay, the code is as below.

```
RewriteRule ^welcome?(.*)                   public/index.php    [L]
RewriteRule ^profile?(.*)                   public/index.php    [L]
RewriteRule ^password?(.*)                  public/index.php    [L]
RewriteRule ^verify(.*)                 public/index.php    [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?%{QUERY_STRING}     [L]
```

Now, the main.php file handles all the request that comes in, even welcome,profile,password,verify. but Now, I want to redirect specific files only to the public/index.php file, which it does in my developer machine but remote server ?

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite in apache on your test server? Does the file public/index.php exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(welcome|profile|password|verify) public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(welcome|profile|password|verify) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php [QSA,L]
```

Give this a try.